# Variations of Hodge structures over the line

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, hodge-theory, hodge-structure

Let $f\colon X\to \mathbb{A}^1$ be a smooth projective morphism of complex algebraic manifolds, where the target $\mathbb{A}^1$ is the affine line. **Are there any restrictions on the Hodge structures on the cohomology groups of fibers of $f$ over different complex points of $\mathbb{A}^1$? (Say are there examples where these Hodge structures are not isomorphic to each other?)**

I apologize if this question is not of the research level; I am not an algebraic geometer. If there is a reference, it would be helpful.

Comment: What is a good example of a nontrivial such family?

Comment: Such a variation of Hodge structure is trivial, by e.g. the theorem of the fixed part, as $\mathbb{A}^1$ is simply connected, so all the Hodge structures are isomorphic.  More is true: by work of Viehweg, Moller, Zuo, and others, "most" moduli spaces are hyperbolic, and so contain no $\mathbb{A}^1$'s...

Comment: Of course one can make examples; for example, families of del Pezzo surfaces; or one may take $X\times\mathbb{A}^1$ for any $X$ containing a rational curve, so that the map $X\times \mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{A}^1$ has a section, and blow up the image of the section.  But I don't know any examples with really "interesting" geometry, for the reasons described in my previous comment.

Comment: @DanielLitt: Thank you for your interesting comment. Could you state explicitly the theorem of the fixed part? This could be a final answer to my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See Theorem 11 on page 191 of [these notes](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~peters/Articles/PubSteen2.pdf).  A special case is as follows.

**Theorem of the fixed part.** Let $S$ be a smooth quasiprojective variety, and $V$ a variation of $\mathbb{Q}$-Hodge structures on $S$ (for example, $R^i\pi_*\underline{\mathbb{Q}}$, for $\pi: X\to S$ a smooth projective morphism).  Then $H^0(S,V)$ naturally admits a Hodge structure, such that the map $H^0(S, V)\to V_s$ is a morphism of Hodge structures for any $s\in S$.

In particular, if $S$ is simply connected (as it is in your case, where we take $S=\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$), then the map $H^0(S,V)\to V_s$ is an isomorphism for any $S$.  Hence all the $V_s$ are isomorphic.